# Angular 8 Material table, MatSort not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to use Angular 8 and display the data in tables.
The data is displayed however sort does not work even though all default changes are made.

MatSortModule is added

Customer Component

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ICustomer>();

@ViewChild(MatSort,{static:false}) sort: MatSort;


ngOnInit() {    
this._customers.getCustomersList().subscribe(data=>{
  this.results=data;   
  this.dataSource=this.results.value;       

  console.log(this.dataSource);
```

});

}

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;` instead of `@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;` the change is only set `static: true`.

Comment: This breaks it completely data is not even displayed after this change

Comment: I edited my answer, try the code and let me know if you can resolve your problem.

Comment: No that did not fix. But the issue was where I initialized my data source. The following line fixed it for me
    this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource<ICustomer>(this.results.value);